# Issue with oauth2 , can't get access_token when it is created

Tags: go, oauth-2.0, token

I've spent nearly 5 hours searching on internet trying to solve this problem and nothing comes up. I want to get my `access_token` when it is created, save it into a variable, and then store it on db. However, I can't extract the created `access_token`.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    oauth2 "gopkg.in/oauth2.v3"
    "gopkg.in/oauth2.v3/models"

    "gopkg.in/oauth2.v3/errors"
    "gopkg.in/oauth2.v3/manage"
    "gopkg.in/oauth2.v3/server"
    "gopkg.in/oauth2.v3/store"
)

func main() {
    manager := manage.NewDefaultManager()

    manager.SetAuthorizeCodeTokenCfg(manage.DefaultAuthorizeCodeTokenCfg)

    manager.MustTokenStorage(store.NewMemoryTokenStore())

    clientStore := store.NewClientStore()
    clientStore.Set("12345", &models.Client{
        ID:     "12345",
        Secret: "12345",
        Domain: "http://localhost:9094",
    })
    manager.MapClientStorage(clientStore)

    srv := server.NewDefaultServer(manager)
    srv.SetAllowGetAccessRequest(true)
    srv.SetClientInfoHandler(server.ClientFormHandler)
    manager.SetRefreshTokenCfg(manage.DefaultRefreshTokenCfg)

    srv.SetInternalErrorHandler(func(err error) (re *errors.Response) {
        log.Println("Internal Error:", err.Error())
        return
    })

    srv.SetResponseErrorHandler(func(re *errors.Response) {
        log.Println("Response Error:", re.Error.Error())
    })

    http.HandleFunc("/token", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        srv.HandleTokenRequest(w, r)
    })

    http.HandleFunc("/protected", validateToken(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

        w.Write([]byte("Hello, I'm protected"))
    }, srv))

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":9099", nil))

}

func validateToken(f http.HandlerFunc, srv *server.Server) http.HandlerFunc {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

        _, err := srv.ValidationBearerToken(r)
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
            return
        }
        f.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}
```

I would appreciate any help, since I'm just a trainee programmer and this is still new for me.

Thanks :).

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, it's impossible to get the token due the plugin do the job for you.!!!